# How can I sum Hours in TimeSpan using Datagridview?

Tags: vb.net

I'm developing this application to record and retrieve employee's labor hours. I was able to save start-time and end-time with the total hours worked into a DataGridView. How do I sum the total hours though? Im getting a logic error on the total hours. This is code and the result i'm getting.

```
For Each ro As DataGridViewRow In dgvHours.Rows
    mydatetime = CDate(ro.Cells(1).Value)
    mytimespan = mytimespan.Add(New TimeSpan(mydatetime.Hour, mydatetime.Minute, 0)))

Next

  dgvHours.Rows.Add("", "")
  dgvHours.Rows.Add("", "")
  dgvHours.Rows.Add("Total: ", mytimespan.Hours & "." & mytimespan.Minutes)
```

[[image: code.PNG[1]]

Comment: You should be using the `TotalHours` property to get the total number of hours.

Comment: Thank you jmcilhinney. Could you please be a little bit more specific?